# phpmailer doesn't send important information (email address entry)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Someone built this site for me and I have no idea about php and which part I should fix :S

Basically I have this single text entry form on my site which users can enter in their email address to that form and once they send submit I'll get the email address they input in.

The dev used phpmailer and at the moment when someone submitted their email address, I don't get any of their email address. The only entry/ email content I get is from "me" and a content of "Thank you. We'll update you as soon as possible."

This is the sendmail.php on the root folder:

```
<?php

$from = "ask@michaelfrieda2014.com";
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']) && $_REQUEST['email'] != '')
{
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
sendMailSingup($from, $email);
sendMailSingup($from, "ask@michaelfrieda2014.com");
}

function sendMailSingup($from, $to)
{
include_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = "Thank you. We'll update you a soon as possible.";    
$mail->From       = "$from";
$mail->FromName   = "";
$mail->Subject    = "Thank you!";    
$mail->AltBody    = "Thank you!"; // optional, comment out and test    
$mail->MsgHTML($body);    
$mail->AddAddress("$to", "");
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");             // attachment
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  #echo "Message sent!";
  echo 1;
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that I get the important information? (Their email address sent to my email). Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below this line...

```
$body = "Thank you. We'll update you a soon as possible.";
```

add:

```
$body .= "<br><br>Sent from: $to";
```

(note the `.=` -- this will append to the $body variable)

---

If you want to fix the `reply-to` address, add this line:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($to, $to);
```

before:

```
$mail->From = "$from";
```

Comment: Now the from is using my email address.. which is ask@michaelfrieda2014.com

Comment: Oh, I see -- sorry. Change all instances of `$from` to `$to`.

Comment: It's still doesn't work. The sender is ask@michaelfrieda2014.com and the content is the same as before:

Thank you. We'll updated you as soon as possible.

Sent from: ask@michaelfrieda2014.com

I think there has to be something off with the form itself..

Comment: Actually, it's kinda working but now it's the other way around.

When I enter in my email address to the site (test@test.com), the email I received says:

Sent from: stuff@friedahandoko.com.au

BUT to my actual email address (ask@michaelfrieda2014.com) it says:

Sent from: ask@michaelfrieda2014.com

It's should be the other way around?

Comment: The reason it needs to come from a trusted email address is for spam control; that's where the reply-to comes in. If it's backwards though, switch $to and $from until it looks right, then test replying to the email to make sure the right one shows up in the To: field